# solutions to overcome "site goes offline due to mysql 'max_user_connections' error."

Tags: mysql, database, drupal

I have been working on eCommerce site (using drupal). Few days ago before i am getting this error my site was working fine no issues was there. But now a days no. of times my site goes offline with the error message ('max_user_connection').

I was using some custom code containing mysql_connect and mysql_query now i changed everything into module and no custom queries left as such.The error is still their. On some of the pages data is populated with two different databases and to handle two database at same page i am using drupal function db_set_active().

I had discussed with hosting provider also they have increased a 'connection_limit' but error is still coming, what will be the possible reasons of having this kind of issue and the ways to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the dbms is not able to serve all incoming connection requests to the database.

You can check with the "show full processlist" (which requires SUPER privilege) for current count of connections.

You now have either two choices: alter you application logic so that overall connections are descreased or you can try to alter the [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) system variable in order to allow your DBMS to server more connections (also requires SUPER privilege).

But if your provider already told you that they increased 'connection_limit, you should go for the first approach (alter your application logic).